# Twisted tap plugin with MultiService requiring some callbacks when starting

Tags: python, twisted

Having the below source code example, **makeService()** starts two services:

1. **AMQP Broker**: Starts a *TCPClient* to connect to an AMQP Broker
2. **HTTPApi**: Starts a **twisted.web.resource.Resource** *TCPServer*

When starting, the second (HTTPApi) requires a ready/available connection to AMQP Broker, when it is not, HTTPApi will fail to start.

I am looking for a clean way how to callback HTTPApi **startHTTPApiService()** when the AMQP Broker is ready, for information, i already have a deferred fired whenever the connection is ready: *self.components['amqp-broker-factory'].getChannelReadyDeferred()*, but how to use it inside **makeService()** ?

Source code:

```
from zope.interface import implements
from twisted.python import usage
from twisted.plugin import IPlugin
from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.web import server
from nimsaj.queues.factory import AmqpFactory
from nimsaj.protocols.http.server import HTTPApi

class nimsajServiceMaker:

    implements(service.IServiceMaker, IPlugin)

    tapname = "nimsaj"
    description = "Network IMS-AJ"
    options = usage.Options
    top_service = None
    components = {}

    def startAMQPBrokerService(self):
        "Start AMQP Broker"

        self.components['amqp-broker-factory'] = AmqpFactory()

        # Add service
        AMQPBrokerService = internet.TCPClient('127.0.0.1', 
                                               5672, 
                                               self.components['amqp-broker-factory'])
        AMQPBrokerService.setServiceParent(self.top_service)

    def startHTTPApiService(self):
        "Start HTTP Api"

        httpApi_f = HTTPApi(self.components['amqp-broker-factory'])

        httpApi = internet.TCPServer(80, 
                                     server.Site(httpApi_f), 
                                     interface = '0.0.0.0'
                                     )
        httpApi.setServiceParent(self.top_service)

    def makeService(self, options):
        self.top_service = service.MultiService()
        self.options = options

        ########################################################
        # Start AMQP Broker
        self.startAMQPBrokerService()

        ########################################################
        # Start HTTP Api
        self.startHTTPApiService()

        return self.top_service

service_maker = nimsajServiceMaker()
```

Comment: Have you seen, https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/5941. Might give some insight.. but it boils down to the same thing.. using `setServiceParent` in a callback to a deferred.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this, I dont know if this is enough in your situation. In my situation I just make sure the the datastore service is not set on the application (and thus does not answer requests) before the database is ready. If there is a better way to handle serrvice dependencies I would also like to know.

```
def setServiceParentWhenDepReady(constraint, service, parent):
    if constraint.running:
        service.setServiceParent(parent)
    else:
        reactor.callLater(0.1, setServiceParentWhenDepReady,
                          *(constraint, service, parent))


def application(config):
    app = Application('appName')

    srv_resolver = SrvResolver()
    app.setComponent(ISrvResolver, srv_resolver)

    postgresservice = PostgresService(app, config)
    postgresservice.setServiceParent(app)
    datastoreservice = RpcService(app, config)
    setServiceParentWhenDepReady(postgresservice, datastoreservice, app)

    return app
```

Comment: This is a good solution but cant be considred as the right answer, i'm looking for the best practice and cleanest way to do things right, in your example, i can see there's no error handling: what will happen if constraint.running wont turn True ?

Comment: yeah, then it will loop forever.. :( You could add a counter in `setServiceParentWhenDepReady(*args, maxretry=100)` something like this that raises an error after `x` attempts... But cleaner solution may exist out there.. Please post it here if you find a nice clean solution.